# How does weapon strengthening work?

Tags: the-last-remnant

Sometimes at the end of battle my companions have their weapons strengthened (+x at the end of a weapon name gets incremented by 1). What triggers this? Can the same happen to my character? Is there a way to increase the odds of it happening?